# Enable Development Mode in .netcoreapp

Tags: .net, .net-core

Does .netcoreaps support the use of developmentMode and DEVPATH?

With .net framework on Windows I use to enable it in .exe.config file, but the same doesn't seems to work when I run an app with dotnet and enable it in .dll.config

Answer (score 3):

Development mode and DEVPATH are supported by .NET Core however it's usage is a bit hidden. It can be set via runtime configuration knobs described in coreclr repo documentation:

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/clr-configuration-knobs.md

To set developer mode on it is necessary to use `developerInstallation` knob which can be set via environment variable.

> When using these configurations from environment variables, the variables need to have the COMPlus_ prefix in their names. e.g. To set DumpJittedMethods to 1, add the environment variable COMPlus_DumpJittedMethods=1

To get it working do the following:

1. Set environment variable `DEVPATH` pointing to location of your development assemblies.
2. Enable `developerInstallation` knob by setting environment variable:

`set COMPlus_developerInstallation=1`

Start your runtime and enjoy DEVPATH and Development Mode feature in .NET Core.

Comment: Doesn't seems to work on Linux, I set `DEVPATH` and `COMPlus_developerInstallation` and still get `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly `

Comment: Hmm ... the code implementing this feature does not seem to be Windows specific - will check it and come back to you.